# Extjs Panel rendering twice?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am new to Extjs. I have configured my app with Extjs 6.6.0 . For every panel I am creating using Ext.create, it generates 2 div elements. The controller init is called twice and so also all other methods.

For exa. Ext.create('something.Mypanel') would called twice and generates 2 div elements in dom.It appends the second div next to the first one. Any clue on it ?

Do I have to change anything in app.json which is loading 2 files  ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. In Application.js , I added the router controller(in controllers property), which made the route to flow twice. I moved the route controller to app.js mainView. Now it's getting called once.